# Grouping a pandas dataframe with categorical strings

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, categorical-data

I have the following df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':['tq','tb','ta','tb','ta','tq','tb','tq','ta'],
                   'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','a'],
                   'col2':['aa','aa','aa','aa','ba','ba','cc','cc','cc'],
                   'val':np.random.rand(9)})
```

I would like to create the following rankings:

```
df['Cat'] = pd.Categorical(df['Cat'],['tb','tq','ta'])
```

However, when I try to do a group by sum:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1','Cat','col2'])['val'].sum()
```

I end up with a 27 row table instead of the desired 8 rows that would occur where I to omit the categorical ranking.

I understand that the 27 is the product of the unique values of `['col1','Cat','col2']`.
I'm wondering how to prevent these permutations in the group by instead of filtering out where `val != 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `observed` argument in `groupby`

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1','Cat','col2'], observed=True)['val'].sum()
df2
# col1  Cat  col2
# a     tq   aa      0.422378
#       tb   aa      0.395679
#       ta   aa      0.407851
#            cc      0.998086
# b     tb   aa      0.318188
#       ta   ba      0.861469
# c     tq   ba      0.333660
#            cc      0.427609
#       tb   cc      0.415207
# Name: val, dtype: float64
```